# How to make efficient a function which checks and update the letters already guessed in a classic Hangman game?

Tags: python, function, call, game-development, dry

I created a classic hangman game in Python. I created a function - called here update_guessed_letters() - which is not called in the following code (to be honest by mistake), because I managed to replace the actions it should do inside the main() function.
My problem is that I would like to keep that update_guessed_letters() function because it would keep the program more "atomical". I tried several things but, after I call that function inside the main(), a few bugs happen: the main of them is that the user can input group of letters (not single letters as it is fundamental to happen).
Any idea?

```
import random
import string



# Constants

HANG_STAGE = [
    r"""
        ,_______________
       ||--------------\
       ||              |
       ||              |
       ||
       ||
       ||
       ||
       ||
       ||
       ||
       ||
       ||\ 
       ||\\ 
       || \\ 
       ||  \\

        """, r"""

        ,_______________
       ||--------------\
       ||              |
       ||             _|_
       ||            {°¿°}
       ||             (¨)
       ||
       ||
       ||
       ||
       ||
       ||
       ||\ 
       ||\\ 
       || \\ 
       ||  \\

        """, r"""

        ,_______________
       ||--------------\
       ||              |
       ||             _|_
       ||            {°¿°}
       ||           __(¨)__
       ||           |   ♂ |   
       ||           |DEATH|
       ||           |_ROW_|
       ||
       ||
       ||
       ||\ 
       ||\\ 
       || \\ 
       ||  \\

        """, r"""

        ,_______________
       ||--------------\
       ||              |
       ||             _|_
       ||            {°¿°}
       ||           __(¨)__
       ||          /|   ♂ |   
       ||         //|DEATH|
       ||        // |_ROW_|
       ||      `¡¡'
       ||
       ||
       ||\ 
       ||\\ 
       || \\ 
       ||  \\

        """, r"""

        ,_______________
       ||--------------\
       ||              |
       ||             _|_
       ||            {ʘ¿ʘ}
       ||           __(¨)__
       ||          /|   ♂ |\   
       ||         //|DEATH|\\
       ||        // |_ROW_| \\
       ||      `¡¡'         '¡¡`
       ||
       ||
       ||\ 
       ||\\ 
       || \\ 
       ||  \\

        """, r"""

        ,_______________
       ||--------------\
       ||              |
       ||             _|_
       ||            {ʘ¿ʘ}
       ||           __(¨)__
       ||          /|   ♂ |\   
       ||         //|DEATH|\\
       ||        // |_ROW_| \\
       ||      `¡¡' / /     '¡¡`
       ||          / /
       ||         | |
       ||\        μμμ 
       ||\\
       || \\
       ||  \\

        """, r"""

        ,_______________
       ||--------------\
       ||              |
       ||             _|_
       ||            {×¿×}
       ||           __(Ü)__
       ||          /|   ♂ |\  
       ||         //|DEATH|\\
       ||        // |_ROW_| \\
       ||      `¡¡' / / \ \ '¡¡`
       ||          / /   \ \ 
       ||         | |     | |
       ||\        μμμ     μμμ
       ||\\
       || \\
       ||  \\

        """
]



TITLE = r"""
 ____    ____      ___________    ____                __________________   ____     ____    _____   _____________     ____
_\HHH\  _\HHH\    _\AAAAAAAAAA\  _\NNN\   ______     /GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG/\ /MMM/_   /MMM/_  /MMMM/_ /AAAAAAAAAAAA/_   /NNN/_
\ \HHH\ \ \HHH\   \________ \AA\ \ \NNN\ /NNNNNN\   /\GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG/ //MMMM\/  /MMM/ / /MMMM/ /  /_______/AA/ /  /NNN/ /
 \ \HHH\ \/HHHH\       ____//AAA\ \ \NNNVNN/ \NNN\  \ \GGG\___________\//MMMMMM\ /MMMM\/ /MMMM/ / _________/AA/ /  /NNNNNNNNN\
  \ \HHH\/H/\HHH\     /AAAAAAAAAA\ \ \NNNN/ \ \NNN\  \ \GGG\    /GGGGG//MMMM/\MM/MMMMAM\/MMMM/ / /AAAAAAAAAAA/ /  /NNN/¯¯\NNNN\
   \ \HHHH/\ \HHH\   /\AAA\___\AAA\_\ \NNN\  \ \NNN\_ \ \GGG\__/GG/\_//MMMM/ /\MMMMM/ \MMMMM/ / /AAA/___/AAA/_/  /NNN/ /¯¯\NNNN\
    \ \HHH\ \ \HHH\__\ \AAA\___\AAAAA\ \NNN\  \ \NNNNN\\ \GGGGGGG/ /_/MMMM/ / /MMMM/ / \MMM/ / /AAA/___/AAAAAA/_/NNN/ /    \NNNN\__
     \ \HHH\ \ \HHHHHH\ \AAAAAAAAAAAAA\ \NNN\  \ \NNNNNN\ \GGGGG/ //MMMMM/ / /MMMM/ /  /MMMM/_/AAAAAAAAAAAAAA/ /NNN/ /     /NNNNNNN|_
      \____\  \_______\\____________\  \____\   \_______\\/_____\/  /_____/  /_____/    /____/ /_______________//___/       /________|

                                                               |¯/¯¯¯i
                                                               |/    i
                                                               |     ð <(life is but a trick)
                                                               |    /|\
                                                               |    / \
                                                               |
"""


"""
I just took a few lines from the Knut Hamsen book called "Hunger"  and I chose them
 as a source for the hangman game.
"""

TEXT = (
    "But my brain got more and more confused. At last I sprang out of bed to look for the water-tap. "
    "I was not thirsty, but my head was in a fever, and I felt an instinctive longing for water. "
    "When I had drunk some I got into bed again, and determined with all my might to settle to sleep. "
    "I closed my eyes and forced myself to keep quiet. I lay thus for some minutes without making a movement, "
    "sweated and felt my blood jerk violently through my veins. No, it was really too delicious the way he "
    "thought to find money in the paper cornet! He only coughed once, too! I wonder if he is pacing up and down "
    "there yet! Sitting on my bench? the pearly blue sea ... the ships...."
    "But my brain got more and more confused. At last I sprang out of bed to look for the water-tap. "
    "I was not thirsty, but my head was in a fever, and I felt an instinctive longing for water. "
    "When I had drunk some I got into bed again, and determined with all my might to settle to sleep. "
    "I closed my eyes and forced myself to keep quiet. I lay thus for some minutes without making a movement, "
    "sweated and felt my blood jerk violently through my veins. No, it was really too delicious the way he "
    "thought to find money in the paper cornet! He only coughed once, too! I wonder if he is pacing up and down "
    "there yet! Sitting on my bench? the pearly blue sea ... the ships...."
    "I opened my eyes; how could I keep them shut when I could not sleep? The same darkness brooded over me; "
    "the same unfathomable black eternity which my thoughts strove against and could not understand. "
    "I made the most despairing efforts to find a word black enough to characterize this darkness; "
    "a word so horribly black that it would darken my lips if I named it. Lord! how dark it was! and I am carried "
    "back in thought to the sea and the dark monsters that lay in wait for me. They would draw me to them, "
    "and clutch me tightly and bear me away by land and sea, through dark realms that no soul has seen. "
    "I feel myself on board, drawn through waters, hovering in clouds, sinking--sinking."
)

GUESSES = len(HANG_STAGE) - 1


# Functions

"""
This function "get an acceptable word" from the constant TEXT and returns it. Then the function
is called into the main() function
"""
def get_acceptable_word(TEXT):
  """
  This eliminates all punctuation
  """
  translation_table = str.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation)
  text = TEXT.translate(translation_table)
  """
  This transformes the text into a list of words
  """
  first_list = text.split()
  """
  This list comprehension removes the duplicates from our original 
  list and the words words smaller than 4 characters, then transform 
  the remaining ones in uppercase
      """
  final_list = [
      i.upper() for n, i in enumerate(first_list)
      if i not in first_list[:n] and len(i) >= 4
  ]
  """
  This chooses and returns a random word from the list of words
  """
  word_in_game = random.choice(final_list)
  return word_in_game



"""
This function asks the user to input his/her name. It doesn't accept punctuation or numbers: just 
alphabetic letters. Then returns a username variable. The function is called inside the main()
"""
def ask_user_name():
    while True:
        username = input("Enter your name: \n")
        if username.isalpha() and not any(char.isspace() for char in username):
            return username
        else:
            print("This is not a concentration camp: no number or spaces allowed. Enter your name again.")


def menu():
    print(r"""
    ʔ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ʕ
    |    THE HANGMAN    |
    |  S. Start Game    |
    |  I. Instructions  |
    |___________________|
        |   |   |   |
        ð   ð   ð   ð
       /|\ /|\ /|\ /|\
       / \ / \ / \ / \
    """)
    while True:
        user_input = input("Press S to start a new game\nPress I for instructions.\n").upper()
        print(end="\n")
        if user_input == "S":
            return True # Start a new game
        elif user_input == "I":
            print("1. The computer will generate a random word, you have to guess it letter by letter.\n"
                 "2. To guess, type a letter (A LETTER) and press enter.\n"
                 "3. If you guess correctly, the letter will be revealed in its exact position in the secret dashed word.\n"
                 "4. If you guess incorrectly, you will lose a life and the poor Hangman will start to appear.\n"
                 "5. You have 6 attempts to guess the correct word: head, torso, two arms and two legs.\nAfter that, you'll become an executioner!\n")
            input("Press any key to go back to the menu\n")
        else:
            print("Remember: S to start a new game, I for instruction. Please try again!\n")


def letter_already_used(letter, guessed_letters):
    """
    Questa funzione verifica se una lettera è già stata utilizzata.
    Restituisce True se la lettera è già presente nella lista delle lettere utilizzate,
    altrimenti restituisce False.
    """
    # Verifica se la lettera è alfabetica
    if not letter.isalpha():
        return False
    return letter in guessed_letters

def update_guessed_letters(letter, guessed_letters, invalid_input_message):
    """
    Questa funzione aggiorna la lista delle lettere già utilizzate con la nuova lettera.
    """
    print("i am working!")
    # Verifica se la lettera è alfabetica
    if not letter.isalpha():
        print(invalid_input_message)
        return
    
    if not letter_already_used(letter, guessed_letters):
        guessed_letters.append(letter)
        print(f"Letters guessed so far: {', '.join(guessed_letters)}", flush=True)
    else:
        print("You've already guessed that letter.", flush=True)

"""
This function manages the end of the game in its two possibilities (play again or exit the game);
it also prints a message in case of invalid input from the user
"""
def end_game(game_over, word_in_display, word_in_game, username):
    if game_over:
        if word_in_display == word_in_game:
            print(f"Congratulations, {username} you guessed the word and saved an innocent life!")
        else:
            print(f"I have a bad news, {username}: you miserably lost the game and killed a man.\nIn any case, the word was: {word_in_game}")
    
    while True:
        play_again = input("Do you want to play again?\nPlease enter 'y' for yes or 'n' for no.\n").lower()
        if play_again == "y":
            return True
        elif play_again == "n":
            print("Thanks for playing!")
            return False
        else:
            print("Seriously? Invalid input. Please enter 'y' for yes or 'n' for no.")



def main():
    global GUESSES
    GUESSES = len(HANG_STAGE) - 1  # Reset GUESSES at the beginning of each game
    print(TITLE)
    if menu():
        word_in_game = get_acceptable_word(TEXT)
        word_in_display = "_" * len(word_in_game)
        game_over = False
        username = ask_user_name()
        print()
        print(f"Ciao, {username}: guess the hidden word and save a life!")
        print()
        print(HANG_STAGE[0])
        print()
        print(word_in_display)
        print()
        guessed_letters = []  # Lista per tenere traccia delle lettere già utilizzate

        while not game_over:
            guessed_letter = input(f"{username}, guess a letter: \n").upper()
            # Verifica se l'input dell'utente è composto da più di una lettera
            if not guessed_letter.isalpha() or len(guessed_letter) != 1:
                print(f"Ehy, {username}, you can only guess LETTERS; one letter at a time, though. Try again.")
                continue  # Ritorna all'inizio del ciclo

            if guessed_letter in guessed_letters:
                print("You've already guessed that letter.")
                continue

            guessed_letters.append(guessed_letter)
            
            if guessed_letter in word_in_game:
                for i in range(len(word_in_game)):
                    if word_in_game[i] == guessed_letter:
                        word_in_display = word_in_display[:i] + guessed_letter + word_in_display[i + 1:]
            else:
                GUESSES -= 1
                print(HANG_STAGE[7 - GUESSES - 1])

            print(f"Letters guessed so far: {', '.join(guessed_letters)}", flush=True)
            print(word_in_display, end="\n\n")

            if GUESSES == 0 or word_in_display == word_in_game:
                game_over = True


        # Call end_game() to handle the end-of-game logic
        play_again = end_game(game_over, word_in_display, word_in_game, username)
        if play_again:
            main() # Restart the game


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This is not a "please review my entire program and help me improve everything about it" general help forum: if you have a _specific_ problem with this code, then please reduce your code to a [mcve] that focuses on [that specific problem](/help/how-to-ask). If not, your post is pretty much [off topic](/help/on-topic) as written.

Comment: You shouldn't worry about efficiency too much for an interactive game. Better to review the structure and functionality first

Comment: Mike, I think I have been very specific with my question. Here when you don't post your entire code is a problem, when you post it is a problem too, when you are specific you get bullied... Thank you for your help